# Datagrid bind to reactive form control

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am wondering if its possible to bind a reactive form's control to the Clarity Design System's datagrid clrDgSelected 2 way binding?

I am using the example here on their [website](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/datagrid/selection) to do a simple datagrid and integrate it with a reactive form.

my form is very simple:

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.testForm= this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      selectionList: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Now i want to incorporate teh selectionList instead of the selected as per the their example.

```
<clr-datagrid [(clrDgSelected)]="selected">
    <-- ... -->
    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let user of users" [clrDgItem]="user">
        <-- ... -->
    </clr-dg-row>
   <-- ... -->
</clr-datagrid>
```

This way i can control form validity as well as ensure the selectionList gets populated directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. It may only work with selections. inputData is whatever may have been persisted from database for example:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.testForm = this.fb.group({
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    selectionList: this.fb.array([])

    this.setSelectionList(inputData);
}

...

setSelectionList(inputData) {
  const initFormGroups = inputData.map(datum => this.fb.group(datum));
  const initFormArray = this.fb.array(initFormGroups);
  this.testForm.setControl('selectionList', initFormArray);
}


get selectionListFCs(): FormArray {
  return this.testForm.get('selectionList') as FormArray;
}

get selected() {
  return this.selectionListFCs.value;
}

set selected(selectedUsers) {
  this.selectionListFCs.setValue(selectedUsers);
}
```